# joomla multiple site component upgrade

Tags: php, linux, joomla

I manage multiple joomla sites across several linux servers that my company owns.

The Joomla's use specific core components that I install and update.

I am wondering if anybody knows of a way to update the same components on mulitple sites at the same time.

Or if someone could point me in the direction of creating a script that will scp the files up and perform the upgrade.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you have to write your own component to do that.  I know the folks at [Directive](http://www.directive.com/home/contact-us.html) have, you can contact them about purchasing it.

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Directive, and was part of the team that designed this, so I'm a bit biased when I say it's pretty nifty.